# Airflow test task works, but in dag run fails

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm wondering why it is possible that the following command works:

`airflow test [dag_id] [task_id] 20200421`

but that the same task fails if I trigger the dag manually in the UI.

The task itself is quite easy, it is basically:

`cmd = 'ls' # other command
os.system(cmd)`

the os library is imported, and like said above, in testing it does work, but in running it does not. My code is in python, and this specific dag needs to run a specific command in the terminal.

Have you got any idea how this is possible?

If you need more info, let me know in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

This problem is due to the different user that runs the script.

`airflow run` uses a different user (and (sub-) processes) as `airflow test`. Switching to the airflow user does not work, but providing the airflow user with more rights (in linux) should work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this behaviour could be, your task that was executed earlier cached in the DB.

So the test works but when you call airflow to run the DAG it fails as it already running in the background or the state is cached in database. Try running $ `airflow resetdb`

Comment: Would this be the same as deleting a (failed) dag run from the UI?

Comment: Also, this cannot be the problem since I tried a new dag run on a new day, and it still failed, while there was no cached dag run.